# Currency question

Tags: design

If a client has the following requirements (below), is there any reason not to request from SF to allow multiple currencies? Are there alternatives to this feature that allow multiple currencies?

Thanks

```
Need to use American Dollars but with option to change to 
•   Canadian Dollars
•   NIS
•   Euro
•   British Pound
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFDC Multi-currency is a very useful feature and is commonly seen in orgs that sell their products in different currencies. I've worked in two orgs that used multi currencies and dated exchange rates `(Advanced Currency Management)` and the feature works well.  You have to remember to change exchange rates every quarter/half/fiscal year if you want to match your ERP system.

ACM is well integrated with `Opportunities` and `Opportunity Products` and you get a lot of stuff for free.

Third party appexchange products will have support for SFDC multicurrency so any roll your own strategy won't be compliant with your ecosystem.

There are some implications for multi-currency when using VF pages. Here are some to consider (there are workarounds)

[apex:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm) limitation (ACM)

> A merge field that references the Salesforce field that is associated with this output field. For example, if you want to display an output field for an account's name field, use value="{!account.name}". You cannot associate this output field with a currency merge field if that field value is calculated using dated exchange rates.

Plus this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SzmMAAS)

Answer (score 4):

You should probably read about the [implications of turning multi-currency on](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_enable_multicurrency_implications.htm&language=en_US) before doing so, once done, it can't be undone.

Unless you implement your own currency management, I'm not sure what other option there would be if the client requires multi-currency. Depends on your use case.